# AWK: Printing lines after they were already processed

Tags: awk

I have a simple file, which is processed by my awk script:

```
AAAAA BBBBBB
CCCCC DDDDDD
EEEEE FFFFFF
GGGGG HHHHHH
IIIII JJJJJJ
```

First, I want to print out one of the last lines, so I start with

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
{if (NR==5){print $0;}}
```

to get `IIIII JJJJJJ` as a result.

Now I want to print line 2 after line 5 was printed out. So I change my script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
{if (NR==5){print $0; NR=2;}
if (NR==2){print $0;}
```

But in this case, it is a never ending loop. How can I print line 5 first and then line 2 without printing line 5 again?

Expected output for clarity:

```
IIIII JJJJJJ
CCCCC DDDDDD
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
awk '{if (NR==2){x=$0} else if (NR==5) {y=$0}} END {print y; print x}' input
```

As we scan the file line-by-line, we store the lines we are interested in in some variables, and then we print them at the end.

And here's a slight simpler alternative:

```
awk '{if (NR==2){x=$0} else if (NR==5) {print $0; print x}}' input
```

This only stores line 2 in a variable. When we reach line 5, we print it and then we print line 2 from the variable.

**Edit**: As William Pursell pointed out, a more idiomatic way to write the above code would be

```
awk 'NR==2 {x=$0} NR==5 {y=$0} END {print y; print x}' input
```

and

```
awk 'NR==2 {x=$0} NR==5 {print $0; print x}' input
```

Comment: Oh you did it using variables. That would do it. Thanks

Comment: More idiomatic to do `awk 'NR==2 {x=$0} NR==5{print $0; print x; }`

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are right, I only provided an answer that would be easier for the OP to understand.

Comment: `awk 'NR==2{s=$0} NR==5{print $0 ORS s}' file`. Don't want the OP thinking you need separate `print` statements for every line of output. If the files is large add `;exit` before `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution by reversing input file (line wise).. requires number of lines in input file to be known and adjust `NR` accordingly:

```
$ tac ip.txt | awk 'NR==1 || NR==4'
IIIII JJJJJJ
CCCCC DDDDDD
```